# Objective-C: Remove duplicate Decimal Separator

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have been trying to use NSScanner or even a for loop in a string to remove duplicate NSDecimalSeparator. How to do that?

Note: NSDecimalSeparator is not "just a comma". It changes according to the iOS current localization. So, any implementation applying a search for duplicate "comma" won't work.

Comment: Duplicated ("100.00.00") or double ("100..00")? If duplicated, which one should remain in string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSDecimalSeparator` is [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDecimalSeparator). I would recommend using `NSNumberFormatter`:

```
//getting default formatter
NSNumberFormatter* numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior: [NSNumberFormatter defaultFormatterBehavior]];

//creating two strings, one with single and one with double separator
NSString *separator = [numberFormatter decimalSeparator];
NSString *doubleSeparator = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", separator, separator];

NSLog(@"decimal separator: %@", separator);

//creating example string
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"single: %@ double: %@", separator, doubleSeparator];

NSLog(@"example string: %@", str);

//replacing double separator with single separator
NSString *modified = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: doubleSeparator withString:separator];

NSLog(@"modified string: %@", modified);
```

**Edit:**
Regarding your comment about "23,45,67" string, here it is:

```
NSString *str2 = @"23,45,67";

NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [str2 componentsSeparatedByString:separator]];

NSString *last = [temp lastObject];

[temp removeLastObject];

NSString *newStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", [temp componentsJoinedByString:@""], separator, last];

NSLog(@"result: %@", newStr);
```

**Edit 2:**
Code to keep only first separator is similar:

```
NSMutableArray *temp2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [str2 componentsSeparatedByString:separator]];

NSString *first = [temp2 objectAtIndex:0];

[temp2 removeObject:first];

NSString *newStr2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", first, separator, [temp2 componentsJoinedByString:@""]];

NSLog(@"result2: %@", newStr2);
```

Comment: Well, this answers one case. A duplicate of decimal separator ",,". But what about "23,45,67"?

Comment: I will try another implementation. It was the decimalSeparator method of NSNumberFormatter that I need (I hope). A for loop or even a scanner will detect a duplicate and remove any further separator(s). Thanks :)

Comment: Well, there is something wrong in your second code. First: you accessed the last object of the temp array, removed it, then used it again in newStr. Second: this code will not remove further separators. You're missing the context. It's a text field where the user may enter many decimal separators. I want just one. Your second code seems to deal with "two" separators. only.

Comment: @ShatouDev 1. Removing last object from mutable array does not mean it's been disposed. 2. The code will remove all separators except for the last one. Isn't that what you wanted? I just replaced the string with `23,45,67,89,12,34,56,78,90`, compiled the code and got `2345678912345678,90` as a result.

Comment: I misinterpret it. I didn't know that removing an object for mutable array doesn't deallocate it. Your implementation is fine, but I'd rather consider the oposite direction (23,4567891234567890).